# Looking for an application that tag and recognizes contemporary music

Tags: music, tags

I am working on finding out some information on few pieces of contemporary music (after or around 1900) that has not been given names, composers or dates.

So I am looking for a web application or something of the sort that recognizes music through uploading music files. SHAZAM is a similar application that works on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Echo Nest makes some pretty wild song analysis applications.  One of their pieces of software is called "Analyze", and seems to take care of what you are looking for:  http://the.echonest.com/analyze/

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) to catalogue music that was improperly or completely untagged.  It works fairly well for a large portion of my music.